# How to generate distance variable using street addresses

Tags: data-transformation, geostatistics

I have data of sold apartments. There is a street address for every apartment and I would like to generate a new variable that tells the distance from the train station. There are over thousand units in the data so I need figure out a efficient way to calculate the distance for each unit.

Sample of data:

**City**, **Street address**

Helsinki, Melkonkatu 21 
Helsinki, Vaasankatu 7 
Helsinki, Siilitie 6 
Helsinki, Muukalaiskatu 2

And the address for train station is "Helsinki, Kaivokatu 1"

Comment: This is programming question rather than an statistics one, but Google Maps and other routing services can do this and they can be automated. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775672/google-maps-api-in-google-spreadsheets-for-distance-miles-or-meters-calculatio

Comment: Without a sample of your data it is really hard to give you any solid advice. Additionally, your question might be off-topic here as it seems you are asking how to calculate a distance based on certain fixed data. If I misunderstand however, and there is some estimation or the like required, it might be a 'statistics' question. Please elaborate.

Comment: My goal is to create statistical model for aparment pricing and the distance from train station would be one of the predictors.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily efficient (though personally I don't consider thousands to be that high of a number data wise) but depending on the region you can download metadata to convert zip/post codes to lat/long coordinates.

For example if you are from the UK you can use:
https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

From here most pieces of software will have a library for calculating distances from lat/long coordinates for example in R you can use the `geosphere` package.